# How to solve System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor

I have a grid which I am selecting the users from. It works fine on some users when I click their id's and on some it breaks and shows the error below:

> An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My coding

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <input type="text" value='@DateTime.Parse(Model.IncidentDate.ToString()).ToString("dd/mm/yyyy"))' class="form-control input-xs" disabled />
</div>
```

Model

```
public string PNumber { get; set; }
public DateTime? IncidentDate { get; set; }
public string CNumber { get; set; }
```

Comment: Because you convert the `DateTime` to `string` and then convert the resulting `string` to `string` again with a format. - its just `Model.IncidentDate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")` but what do you think the point of this - what are you trying to acheive?

Comment: Your IncidentDate property is nullable. Is that exception thrown, when you have a null value for IncidentDate?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to have a date in that format. I just don't know how i can work it around.

Comment: The its just `value="@Model.IncidentDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"` but you disabling it so what is the point of using an input? But you really should be using `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IncidentDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class="form-control input-xs" })`

Comment: Sorry , This is a calendar that am selecting from and i can see that this doesn't allows the user to select from the text box and also the style on the control disappears

Comment: What does that have to do with it? And if you want it to be disabled, then just make it `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IncidentDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class="form-control input-xs" , disabled="disabled" })` although it disabled controls will not be submitted to the server when you submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IncidentDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control input-xs", disabled = "disabled" })
```

If no value has been set for `IncidentDate` then it will display an empty textbox. If a value has been set then it will display a textbox with a date in it, for example:

```
04/05/2016
```

The above values representing the following:

```
04 - dd
05 - MM
2016 - yyyy
```